Can I iterate over resources.repositories in a pipeline?
resources.repositories appears to be a list, so I'm hoping I can iterate over it without having to hack around.
I'm trying to make a pipeline that would look something like this:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: firstRepo
      name: MyProject/firstRepo
      type: git
    - repository: secondRepo
      name: MyProject/secondRepo
      type: git

stages:
  - stage: DoThing
    jobs:
    - ${{ each repo in variables.repositories }}:
      - template: /templates/doThing.yaml
        parameters:
          repoName: ${{ repo.name }}

When attempting to run the pipeline I get stopped by an error:

/pipelines/azure-pipelines.yaml (Line: 13, Col: 7): Unrecognized value: 'resources'. Located at position 1 within expression: resources.repositories. For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

The multi-repo checkout documentation says:

When you check out multiple repositories, some details about the self repository are available as variables. When you use multi-repo triggers, some of those variables have information about the triggering repository instead. Details about all of the repositories consumed by the job are available as a template context object called resources.repositories.

That template context object link has this to say:

Within a template expression, you have access to the parameters context that contains the values of parameters passed in. Additionally, you have access to the variables context that contains all the variables specified in the YAML file plus many of the predefined variables (noted on each variable in that article). Importantly, it doesn't have runtime variables such as those stored on the pipeline or given when you start a run. Template expansion happens early in the run, so those variables aren't available.

If it's available within the template context, it should be fine to use it as per my example. However, all the examples of using resources.repositories use it with runtime expression syntax, and always specify an alias (e.g, firstRepo) and variable (e.g, ref) when using it. For example: $[resources.repositories.firstRepo.name.
Is this possible?

AFAIK it's not possible to iterate over the list of resources. Could you please provide more context? What are you planning to do with ${{ repo.name }}?

I'd be checking out the repo so as @RuiJarimba said, I'd need to use the alias to do that anyway.

Did any of the below answers help?

As far as I know, it's not possible to iterate over the list of pipeline resources.
As a workaround consider adding a parameter with the list of repositories - example:
parameters:
  - name: repositories
    displayName: List of repositories used by this pipeline
    type: object
    default:
      - MyProject/firstRepo
      - MyProject/secondRepo

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: firstRepo
      name: MyProject/firstRepo
      type: git
    - repository: secondRepo
      name: MyProject/secondRepo
      type: git

stages:
  - stage: DoThing
    jobs:
    - ${{ each repo in parameters.repositories }}:
      - template: /templates/doThing.yaml
        parameters:
          repoName: ${{ repo }}

This approach adds a bit of duplication and you need to keep the parameter and resources in sync. But, on the other hand, you can iterate over the repositories parameter.
Please note that if you want to manually checkout the code you need to use the repository alias (e.g. firstRepo) instead of the repository name (e.g. MyProject/firstRepo):
steps:
  - checkout: firstRepo

  # other steps ...


According to Repository resource variables,

In each run, the following metadata for a repository resource is available to all jobs in the form of runtime variables.

resources.repositories..name
resources.repositories..ref
resources.repositories..type
resources.repositories..id
resources.repositories..url
resources.repositories..version


It means that these variables are only available during the runtime. However, template expansion happens early in the run and these variables haven't been available.
About Details about all of the repositories consumed by the job are available as a template context object called resources.repositories., it is just to show that it can be consumed like a template object, resources.repositories, not to say that it is available in a template expression.
If you want to checkout repo in the template, it would be a good choice to use paramaters as mentioned by @Rui Jarimba.
